# Available cameras in ActionScript 3

Tags: arrays, string, camera

I know to how create the camera object in as3 you use camera = Camera.getCamera(); What I am attempting to do is create an array of strings of all available cameras that are supported on a clients computer So the client has a selection to choose from instead of using the default camera. How do I do this? This is what I have so far:
Thanks

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(320,200,30);
cam.setQuality(0,85);
cam.setKeyFrameInterval(18);
ns.attachCamera(cam);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create that array - it already [exists](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#names).

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < Camera.names.length; i++) {
    trace(Camera.names[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Hunter. That's all I needed to know.